# Make a Snake Parser!

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Snakes look like this:

```
      >>>v
@     ^  v
^  >>>^  v
^        v
^<<<<<<<<<
```

The snake can cross over itself as in this case:

```
 @
 ^
>^>v
 ^<<
```

For a crossover to be valid, the characters on either side must be moving the same direction. The case of

```
 @
>^v
 ^<
```

can be considered unclear and invalid.

The output is a string of `WASD` representing going from the head to the tail  (`@`).

**Given a snake that doesn't backtrack and isn't ambiguous, can you write a program that will output the string of moves that the snake takes?**

This is code-golf, so shortest answer wins!

#### Test cases:

<sub>(Note: The `@` can be replaced with any character not in `v^<>`)</sub>

**Input:**

```
>>>>v
    v
  v<<  @
  v    ^
  >>>>>^
```

**Output:** `ddddssaassdddddww`

---

**Input:**

```
@>>v
^  v
^  v
^<<<
```

**Output:** `dddsssaaawww`

---

**Input:**

```
>>>v
   v       @
   v       ^
   >>>>v   ^
       >>>>^
```

**Output:** `dddsssddddsddddwww`

---

**Input:**

```
@<< v
  ^ v
v<^<<
v ^
>>^
```

**Output:** `ssaaaassddwwwwaa`

---

**Input:**

```
@v<v
^v^v
^v^<
^<
```

**Output:** `ssawwasssawww`

Comment: Does the input have to be a single String or can we take a String[]? Is each line of the input padded to be the same length or do we have to deal with irregular line length?

Comment: This is giving me horrible flash backs to the path of an Ant on a rubiks cube question.

Comment: Will the beginning segment always be on line 0, char 0, or will we have to find it?

Comment: @SpeedyNinja test cases 2 and 4 both have starts not at (0,0), and test case 0 (snakes look like) doesn't start OR end at (0,0).

Comment: @CAD97 Oh, that's devlish ;)

Comment: Can two 4-way intersections in a row be next to each other?  e.g., [`ddddsawwass`](http://imgur.com/OPON1hb)

Comment: @CAD97 Okay, does this look better?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37258/discussion-between-solver-and-cad97).

Answer (score 7):

### Java, <s>626</s> <s>539</s> <s>536</s> 529 bytes

*-87 bytes by saving a few in a lot of places. Thanks goes to Mr Public for pointing some out.*

*-3 bytes because I can't manage to remove all the spaces first try (thanks mbomb007)*

*+8 bytes to fix for this case:*

```
@v<v
^v^v
^v^<
^<
```

*-15 bytes by front-loading variable declaration*

```java
s->{String o="",t;String[]p=s.split("\n");int h=p.length,w=p[0].length(),y=0,x,b=0,a,n,m;char[][]d=new char[h][w];for(;y<h;y++)for(x=0;x<w;x++){d[y][x]=p[y].charAt(x);if(d[y][x]=='@')d[y][x]=' ';}for(;b<h;b++)for(a=0;a<w;a++){t="";x=a;y=b;n=0;m=0;while(!(y<0|y>h|x<0|x>w||d[y][x]==' ')){if(y+m>=0&y+m<h&x+n>=0&x+n<w&&d[y+m][x+n]==d[y-m][x-n])d[y][x]=d[y-m][x-n];n=m=0;switch(d[y][x]){case'^':t+="W";m--;break;case'<':t+="A";n--;break;case'v':t+="S";m++;break;case'>':t+="D";n++;}x+=n;y+=m;}o=t.length()>o.length()?t:o;}return o;}
```

Readable version:

```java
static Function<String,String> parser = snake -> {
    // declare all variables in one place to minimize declaration overhead
    String output = "", path;
    String[] split = snake.split("\n");
    int h=split.length, w=split[0].length(), y=0, x, startY=0, startX, dx, dy;
    char[][] board = new char[h][w];
    // setup char[][] board
    for (; y<h; y++)
        for (x=0; x<w; x++) {
            board[y][x]=split[y].charAt(x);
            if(board[y][x]=='@')board[y][x]=' ';
        }
    // find the longest possible path
    for (; startY<h; startY++)
        for (startX=0; startX<w; startX++) {
            path = "";
            x=startX; y=startY; dx=0; dy=0;
            while (!(y<0 | y>h | x<0 | x>w || board[y][x] == ' ')) {
                if (y + dy >= 0 & y + dy < h & x + dx >= 0 & x + dx < w
                        && board[y + dy][x + dx] == board[y - dy][x - dx]) {
                    board[y][x] = board[y - dy][x - dx];
                } dx = dy = 0;
                switch(board[y][x]) {
                    case '^':path+="W";dy--;break;
                    case '<':path+="A";dx--;break;
                    case 'v':path+="S";dy++;break;
                    case '>':path+="D";dx++;break;
                }
                x+=dx; y+=dy;
            }
            output = path.length()>output.length()?path:output;
        }
    return output;
};
```

Takes a String like `v  @\n>>>^`.
Creates a path starting at each coordinate, then returns the longest one.
The lookahead required for the overlapping paths was the hardest part.

Comment: I am very impressed. I didn't expect _anyone_ to even attempt this. And you're the first one. +1. (2016 bytes is okay, and even better for 2016 :D)

Comment: Strip all the spaces, names, etc then I'll +1. I'm not voting up until it's golfed properly.

Comment: Or, have two code snippets, one of the fully golfed version, one of the working readable example.

Comment: @mbomb007 I finished the logic golfing so here's the properly golfed version!

Comment: @CAD97 Probably just an oversight, replace variables `dx` and `dy` with a 1 character long variable name. Also, I believe you can set an `int L=b.length;` and you should save a few bytes since `b.length` is repetitive.

Comment: @CAD97 Also, kind of obscure, but consider this for-loop: `int y=0,x;for(;y<3;y++)for(x=0;x<3;x++)` is 1 byte less than `for(int y=0;y<3;y++)for(int x=0;x<3;x++)`

Comment: @MrPublic are you trying to run me out of one-letter variable names with any sort of meaning? Anyway, I put your things in and fixed the `for(;;)if()break;` to be `while()`, for a gain of -87 bytes.

Comment: Can you use `|` instead of `||` for any of those? Or `for(x=0;x++<3;)`? Also, remove spaces in `char[][] d = new char`.

Comment: @mbomb007 I just ninja'd you on `|` vs `||`. The last one needs to short circuit but the others don't. The value of the loop variables matters too much to change incrimination from the end of the loop to the beginning.

Comment: @CAD97 For this challenge, I would say this is an excellent golf in Java.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 217

```ruby
->a{r=''
z=a.index ?@
a.tr!('<^>v',b='awds').scan(/\w/){c=0
e,n=[a[z,c+=1][?\n]?p: c,d=c*a[/.*
/].size,a[z-c,c][?\n]?p: -c,-d].zip(b.chars).reject{|i,k|!i||a[v=i+z]!=k||0>v}.max_by{|q|q&[a[z]]}until n
z+=e
r=n*c+r}
r}
```

This starts at the `@` and walks backwards, looking for neighbors that point to the current position (`z`).  In order to choose the right way at 4-way intersections, it favors neighbors pointing in the same direction (`max_by{...}`).  If no immediate neighbors are found, it assumes that there must have been a cross-over and reaches out one level at a time until it finds one (`until n` and `c+=1`).  This process repeats for the number of body segments (not including the head) (`.scan(/\w/){...}`).

The test case I added to the puzzle kept tripping me up, so I went form 182 char to 218.  Those extra characters were all making sure my horizontal moves didn't go into the next/prev lines.  I wonder if I can deal with that in a better way.

### Ungolfed:

```ruby
f=->a{
  result=''
  position=a.index ?@ # start at the @
  a.tr!('<^>v',b='awds') # translate arrows to letters
  a.scan(/\w/){           # for each letter found...
    search_distance=0
    until distance
      search_distance+=1
      neighbors = [
        a[position,search_distance][?\n]?p: search_distance,  # look right by search_distance unless there's a newline
        width=search_distance*a[/.*\n/].size,   # look down (+width)
        a[position-search_distance,search_distance][?\n]?p: -search_distance, # look left unless there's a newline
        -width                  # look up (-width)
      ]
      distance,letter = neighbors.zip(b.chars).reject{ |distance, letter_to_find|
        !distance || # eliminate nulls
         a[new_position=distance+position]!=letter_to_find || # only look for the letter that "points" at me
         0>new_position # and make sure we're not going into negative indices
       }.max_by{ |q| 
        # if there are two valid neighbors, we're at a 4-way intersection
        # this will make sure we prefer the neighbor who points in the same 
        # direction we're pointing in.  E.g., when position is in the middle of 
        # the below, the non-rejected array includes both the top and left.
        #   v
        #  >>>
        #   v
        # We want to prefer left.
        q & [a[position]] 
        # ['>',x] & ['>'] == ['>']
        # ['v',x] & ['>'] == []
        # ['>'] > [], so we select '>'.
       }
    end
    position+=distance
    result=(letter*search_distance)+result # prepend result
  }
  result # if anyone has a better way of returning result, I'm all ears
}
```

Comment: You should be able to simplify your logic somewhat as your added case has been deemed out of the intended scope.